# MS GraphServiceClient To Add Event List Item in Sharepoint Getting Invalid Argument

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

The c# code (below) is what I am testing with. Getting by permissions, etc. Get List Item test is working. There AddAsync method with the following payload in the ListItem object below is getting the invalid argument. The Title, Start Time and End Time are required fields. I am unable to find anything specific on event list date formats for MS graph. I am using the ListItem object but not sure what is the bad argument in it. Any help is appreciated. Please advise. TIA

```
       _scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            _graphSettings.TenantId, _graphSettings.ClientId, _graphSettings.ClientSecret, options);
        
        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, _scopes);


        var listItem = new ListItem
        {
            Fields = new FieldValueSet
            {
                AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"Title", "MS Graph API Test"},
                    {"Description", "Proof of Concept Test"},
                    {"Location", "East Club" },
                    {"Start Time", "2022–06–28T09:00:00" },
                    {"End Time", "2022–06–28T15:00:00" }
                }
            }
        };

        await _graphClient.Sites["{_graphSettings.SharepointSiteId}"].Lists["{_graphSettings.EventListId}"].Items
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(listItem);
```

Comment: I added a $ to the variables in the add async and get no error, however, I am not getting the list item created either.                                await _graphClient.Sites[$"{_graphSettings.SharepointSiteId}"].Lists[$"{_graphSettings.EventListId}"].Items
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(listItem);

Comment: I am not having a permission issue. I have both deletegate and application permissions for Site.ReadWriteAll. I took your advice and went to graph explorer. There are 2 sharepoint tabs and neither one provide a post option. They are all getters. Should I interpret this as sharepoint posts from ms graph are not supported in sharepoint or at least the shareport version we are on?

Answer (score 0):

- Before trying it programmatically, try  working on the [Microsoft
  Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)
- Please make sure you are giving Microsoft graph api permissions to
  write to the sharepoint site before operation.

give `Sites.ReadWrite.All` Application permission , if it is user make sure Sites.ReadWrite.All delegated permission is given.
[image]

Also make sure to grant permsissions for the same.
Check if Content_Type needs to be given in request headers.

try without giving start and end date.

> Note:Please recheck with the siteId and ListId

Reference: [listitem-create | microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I havent but will try graph explorer. I cannot try without start and end dates as they are required on the event list object, although I have tried without start and end dates on an event widget as those dates are not required. I received the same response The error I receive states a bad argument in the additional fields property. I followed the MS docs and I am using the graph service client for c#.

Comment: I have the access configured properly for Sites.ReadWriteAll. I am able to read the lists in sharepoint with no issue but cant get by the bad argument response